# How to assert Elixir messages arrive in order

Tags: elixir

I am building an Elixir module that sends message in certain order. And I wrote unit tests like this

```
MyModule.send_msgs(self())
assert_received {:event, 1}
assert_received {:event, 2}
assert_received {:event, 3}
```

The problem is, even if I shuffle the `assert_received` order, the test still passes.

```
MyModule.send_msgs(self())
assert_received {:event, 2}
assert_received {:event, 1}
assert_received {:event, 3}
```

It seems `assert_received` doesn't care about the order of message arrival. Not just `assert_received`, as far as I recall, `receive` can also get messages out of order.
So, my question here is, how can you ensure the order of arriving message if they can be received out of order?

Comment: You should probably not rely on messages arriving in order in the first place. You could for example order the messages in the receiver as you build up state there. If necessary, send the ordering index along with the message.

Comment: @PatrickOscity that may be too inefficient. Many modules, e.g. `gen_tcp` send data in messages without index and relies on the fact that it's guaranteed that messages sent from process A to B are guaranteed to arrive in order.

Comment: @Dogbert I see, thanks for the clarification. Somehow I had a more generic scenario in mind -- probably because of some code I was working on lately, were multiple processes were sending messages to a "collector" process. Of course in that case, no such guarantees for ordering of incoming messages can be made.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be an existing function to do this, but it's easy to make your own macro which asserts that the next message in the mailbox matches a specific pattern:

```
defmacro assert_next_receive(pattern, timeout \\ 100) do
  quote do
    receive do
      message ->
        assert unquote(pattern) = message
    after unquote(timeout) ->
      raise "timeout" # you might want to raise a better message here
    end
  end
end
```

Test:

```
defmodule MTest do
  use ExUnit.Case

  def send_msgs(pid) do
    send pid, {:event, 1}
    send pid, {:event, 2}
    send pid, {:event, 3}
  end

  defmacro assert_next_receive(pattern, timeout \\ 100) do
    quote do
      receive do
        message ->
          assert unquote(pattern) = message
      after unquote(timeout) ->
        raise "timeout" # you might want to raise a better message here
      end
    end
  end

  test "should pass" do
    send_msgs(self())
    assert_next_receive {:event, 1}
    assert_next_receive {:event, 2}
    assert_next_receive {:event, 3}
  end

  test "should fail" do
    send_msgs(self())
    assert_next_receive {:event, 1}
    assert_next_receive {:event, 3}
    assert_next_receive {:event, 2}
  end
end
```

Output:

```
.

  1) test should fail (MTest)
     test/m_test.exs:29
     match (=) failed
     code:  {:event, 3} = message
     right: {:event, 2}
     stacktrace:
       test/m_test.exs:32: (test)



Finished in 0.05 seconds
2 tests, 1 failure

Randomized with seed 351622
```

Comment: Awesome! trying to understand how this works and how it's different from `assert_received` and `assert_receive`. So for `assert_receive`, they trying to match messages with exactly the desired pattern in the inbox, and by doing that, it doesn't matter what's the order of the desired one in inbox, it can match out of order. But the way you did it, was to match any message and assert it. As it's any message, it will get always msg in FIFO order. Am I understanding it correctly?

Comment: Yes, `assert_received` and `assert_receive` picks the first message matching the pattern, while my `assert_next_receive` asserts that the first message in the mailbox matches the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite late but here's what I would do. Within the receiving process, take a look into its mailbox

```
pid = self()
{:message, messages} = Process.info(pid, :messages)

assert Enum.sort(messages) == messages
```

Maybe I have missed something but apparently it is quite straight forward.